# How can I create a flash program with consistent performance across multiple machines?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, biometrics

I want to create a flash program that tracks mouse and keyboard biometrics such as mouse movement speed, click rate, length of keystrokes and so forth.  How can I ensure that if a user duplicates his/her actions across multiple machines with varying processor speeds I will record the same data?

Comment: you cant, you can only spoof it.

Answer (score 2):

You could sign all your data with a Number given by [`getTimer()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer%28%29) - this will mean your data is timestamped with the amount of milliseconds since the application was launched - regardless of processor speed, etc.

Example:

```
public class DocClass extends Sprite
{
    // vars
    private var _log:Array = [];

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function DocClass()
    {
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _click);
    }

    /**
     * MouseEvent.CLICK
     */
    private function _click(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
>>      _log[_log.length] = {time:getTimer(), data:"CLICK"};
    }

    /**
     * Output the log
     */
    public function outputLog():void
    {
        var i:Object;
        for each(i in _log)
        {
            trace(i.time + ": " + i.data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set frameRate of your SWF to something big like 60 fps (AFAIK, bigger number will give no speedup) and keep graphic effects and code computations simple. This way you'll get high frame rate. You need it because your code awakens only between frames rendered by player, and big fps will increase time resolution.
Then measure your data using real time given by getTimer. If your application will be able to run at 60 fps, one frame will last for 1000/60 = 16.666 milliseconds, so you can hope your data is that precise.
*(@Marty Wallace: getTimer() returns int, not Number)*